# how to solve snakemake 5.32.0 env problem

Tags: snakemake

i had meet a problem when i run snakemake in cluster system, "missingoutputfile" and i had searched trying to solve the problem, maybe because it is "run" derived, not "shell",   and it is a bug, in the new verision you had solve this problem, when i update it (verison 5.32.0). but another problem is raising up.

```
Error in rule predict_plasforest:
    jobid: 34
    output: linear_plasmid_genome/DP-Sample058-S54-adapter-phix-moving-sickle-sss_contigs_1kb.csv
    log: log/isolating-linear-contig/DP-Sample058-S54-adapter-phix-moving-sickle-sss_linear_plasforest.out, log/isolating-linear-contig/DP-Sample058-S54-adapter-phix-moving-sickle-sss_linear_plasforest.err (check log file(s) for error message)
    conda-env: /home/projects/ku_00041/apps/wanli/F_pipeline/conda_envs/60d0848d
    shell:
        export PATH=$PATH:/home/projects/ku_00041/apps/wanli/F_pipeline/db/blast/bin;cp /home/projects/ku_00041/apps/wanli/F_pipeline/db/plasforest/plasmid_refseq.* .;cp /home/projects/ku_00041/apps/wanli/F_pipeline/db/plasforest/plasforest.sav .;python3 /home/projects/ku_00041/apps/wanli/F_pipeline/db/plasforest/PlasForest.py -i assmebly_res/DP-Sample058-S54-adapter-phix-moving-sickle-sss_contigs_1kb.fasta -r -b -f --threads 30 -o linear_plasmid_genome/DP-Sample058-S54-adapter-phix-moving-sickle-sss_contigs_1kb.csv 2>log/isolating-linear-contig/DP-Sample058-S54-adapter-phix-moving-sickle-sss_linear_plasforest.err >log/isolating-linear-contig/DP-Sample058-S54-adapter-phix-moving-sickle-sss_linear_plasforest.out
        (one of the commands exited with non-zero exit code; note that snakemake uses bash strict mode!)
    cluster_jobid: 30135295
```

when i see the log file:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/projects/ku_00041/apps/wanli/F_pipeline/db/plasforest/PlasForest.py", line 26, in <module>
    from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn'
```

but in the conda-env, it has already install sklean. and when i activate this env and reun the same command, it is working.

did you know how to solve this problem?

Comment: Do you run snakemake from the activated environment? Sounds like that is the main problem.

Comment: I'm aware of [snakemake's conda support via `conda:`](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/deployment.html#integrated-package-management) but didn't know `conda-env:` existed. And I don't see anything about it in the documentation or source code (in quick search). Perhaps that's the issue?

Comment: i had tested it, it is snakemake not activate conda envs, and i tried with version 5.25.0 is working, and the version >5.25.0 all have the problem. but one thing is 5.25.0 version sometimes will raise errors which is "MissingOutputException", randomly, which means the same rule sometimes will raise this kind of error, and sometimes are not.  i add a params "--latency-wait 60", now it seems like solveing this problem, but i don`t know whether it will raise again

Comment: You wrote: `maybe because it is "run" derived, not "shell"`. Your intuition may be correct. Snakemake being a python package, things inside `run` will use Python packages belonging to the same Python installation as snakemake. Things inside `shell` might use a different Python installation. The PATH or conda-env used for the execution of your rule might play a role in your issue. Check the content of `/home/projects/ku_00041/apps/wanli/F_pipeline/db/blast/bin`, to be sure.